# Random output from forumla in C

Tags: c

I'm getting random answers when I run my formula as such:

```
    int main (void)
{
    int F = 120;


    printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, (F - 32) / 1.8);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I change the code to this:

```
    int main (void)
{
    int F = 120, C;

    C = (F-32)/1.8;
    printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, C);

    return 0;
}
```

It's consistent and gives the correct answer. 
why doesn't the first version work correctly?

Comment: Hint: operator precedence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in your first version, you do `32/1.8` before minusing the result to `F` in `F - ...`:

```
printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, F - 32 / 1.8); //32/1.8 gets operated first
```

Thus you get `F - 17.777777778` all the time in your first version.

The `/` division has higher precedence than `-`. Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) out.

Another issue which you encounter is that the `C` is of `int` type. Thus printing it with `%i` fits in the second version:

```
int F = 120, C;

C = (F-32)/1.8; //C is int, so the result is rounded here
printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, C); //printing int with %i is OK
```

But note that in your first version, the result of `F - 32 / 1.8` will be **type-promoted** to floating point (like `float/double`) but you are trying to print floating point with `%i` format.

```
printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, F - 32 / 1.8);
//The F - 32 / 1.8 expression here is 
//int - int / double -> resulting in double type
//but you print double type with %i -> does not match
```

Solution: gives parentheses and change the printing format to `%f` to print floating point:

```
printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %f\n", F, (F - 32) / 1.8); //note the %f
```

Comment: even with the proper parenthesis, it doesn't gove the correct answer. One time i'l run the program and I'll get something like: -1040235848 then something like: -371432504

Comment: @StevenLutz I address that.

Comment: I see, by printing the output as a float I get the correct answer every time.
However, I don't unserstand why. can you elaborate on what causes this issue?
Thank you

Comment: @StevenLutz ah, yes. There is a proper format for every printing. Also beware of type promotion in your expression. The `(F-32)/1.8` is promoted as floating point type

Comment: when printing as int, why doesn't it just get truncated?

Comment: @StevenLutz no, it does not work that way... because integer and floating point representation of numbers are totally different representation... The printing format does not do truncation - they are different from assignment operation like `int a = (double)b`. They just got your value (binary 1 and 0) and print it out according to your specified format (integer case: `%i`). if you want to print it as integer, you got to `cast` the result to `int`. Something like this: `(int)((F-32)/1.8)` - it will make the data become `int` type. And then you print it with `%i` format...

Comment: I actually just tried casting it as well and I'm getting a similar errored result as before with code like:

printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, (int) (F-32)/1.8);

Comment: you miss one parentheses... it is still a `double` because of `(int)(int-int)/double` = `double`. Put one more parentheses: `(int)((F-32)/1.8)` -> `(int)((int-int)/double)` = `int` to give you `int` result. Also, `printf` does not do math operation for you, it is just reading and displaying. Thus, it is our responsibility to write proper format for the `printf` to display the result correctly...

Answer (score 0):

This is because division operator `"/"`has higher preference than the subtraction operator `"-"`, in the first example you use are not using brackets therefore division takes place first, you can change your code to :

`printf("%f Farenheit in Celsius is %f\n", F, (F - 32) / 1.8);`

and it would work perfectly.

Comment: even with the proper parenthesis, it doesn't gove the correct answer. One time i'l run the program and I'll get something like: -1040235848 then something like: -371432504

Comment: @Steven Lutz as pointed out by Ian and R sahu, you are doing floating point division but using `%i`.

Comment: ok, I understand better now, but I don't fully understand where these seemingly random numbers are coming from when printing the answer with the wrong type. why doesn't it just get truncated?

Comment: @Steven Lutz using incorrect modifier is `undefined behavior` , i.e it can do anything. You can read more about it here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use of the format specification `%i` for floating point numbers is cause for undefined behavior. Use `%f`.

```
printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %f\n", F, (F - 32) / 1.8);
                                   ^^^
```

In the second case, you are truncating the number when you use:

```
C = (F-32)/1.8;
```

The second `printf` prints the truncated number since you are using `%i` with `C`, which is an `int`.

Comment: even with the proper parenthesis, it doesn't gove the correct answer.
One time i'l run the program and I'll get something like:
-1040235848
then something like:
-371432504

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in:

```
F - 32 / 1.8
```

Division `/` has higher precedent than minus `-`. `32/1.8` gets evaluated first, then the result is substracted from `F`

What you should be doing is:

```
(F - 32) / 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

With `printf("%i Farenheit in Celsius is %i\n", F, (F - 32) / 1.8);`:

The compiler passes the **double value** of `(F - 32) / 1.8` to function `printf`.

It cannot determine that you want to pass the **integer value** of `(F - 32) / 1.8`.

This is because the argument containing `"%i"` is parsed **only during runtime**.

The result is undefined, as `printf` sees `"%i"` and loads an `int` from the stack.